Visual Studio Code keyboard shortcut to toggle word wrap for all editors
In Visual Studio Code, you can change word wrap for a single editor with the command “View: Toggle Word Wrap”. A keyboard shortcut can be bound to this command.
Alternatively, you can change word wrap for all editors from “Settings > Text Editor > Editor: Word Wrap”. Is there a way to toggle word wrap between off and on for all editors using a single key sequence (similar to Ctrl+E+W in Visual Studio)?

Does this answer your question? How can I switch word wrap on and off in Visual Studio Code?

@Charley That question doesn’t ask about keyboard shortcuts. Some of the answers mention keyboard shortcuts, but those are only for toggling word wrap for a single editor. This question asks for a keyboard shortcut to toggle word wrap for all editors.
